# How can I rotate a rectangle complete 360 degree

Tags: trigonometry, rotations, math-software, rectangles

I implemented the logic to rotate rectangle $90$ degree but the logic is not working for complete $360$. It rotates until $90$ then goes in reverse direction until $180$ then again come back on $225$ then again goes in reverse direction for $360$.

Means its going and coming back only in one quadrant.

The method I used is

1. Found the center of rectangle
2. Changed centre of position to orgin
3. Did rotation
4. Took back to original position

Logic used is
$(x\cos\theta−y\sin\theta ,x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)$.

Do I need another logic for complete $360$ degree rotation?

Comment: What software is doing the rotating?

Comment: C++ I used to rotate

Comment: For the angle you should be using atan2

Comment: I suggest that you either post this on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) with the associated code. Or here, but with the mathematical equations you used. There should be a mistake somewhere, but what you provide is not detailed enough to investigate.

Comment: I took angle in randiance then applied cos and sin using Cmath library

Comment: Sure  mathcounterexamples.net, Thanks

Comment: This is probably a coding issue rather than a maths issue, your transformation is ok.